# VBA/Macro to copy random rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: vba, random, macros, conditional-statements

I need help to be able to get random rows from another workbook with specific conditions:

If i click a button/run a macro, I should get something like this :

- 4 random rows for all rows that has "AU"
- 1 random row for all rows that has "FJ"
- 1 random row for all rows that has "NC"
- 3 random rows for all rows that has "NZ"
- 1 random row for all rows that has "SG12"

ALL FROM `Raw Data_Park Sampling.xlsx` "`Sheet1`" sheet and paste it to `Park Sampling Tool.xlsm` "`Random Sample`" sheet.

All should happen in one click.

Below is the whole code i got.

```
Sub MAINx1()


'Delete current random sample

Sheets("Random Sample").Select
Cells.Select
Range("C14").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp




    Dim rawDataWs As Worksheet, randomSampleWs As Worksheet
    Dim map, i As Long, n As Long, c As Long, rand, col
    Dim keyArr, nRowsArr
    Dim rng As Range


    Set rawDataWs = Workbooks("Raw Data_Park Sampling.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set randomSampleWs = Workbooks("Park Sampling Tool.xlsm").Worksheets("Random Sample")
    randomSampleWs.UsedRange.ClearContents

    'Set map = RowMap(rawDataWs.Range("A2:A923"))


     Set rng = rawDataWs.Range("A2:A" & _
                    rawDataWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    Set map = RowMap(rng)

     keyArr = Array("AU", "FJ", "NC", "NZ", "SG12", "ID", "PH26", "PH24", "TH", "ZA", "JP", "MY", "PH", "SG", "VN") '<== keywords

     nRowsArr = Array(4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2) '<== # of random rows



    'Debug.Print "Key", "#", "Row#"
    For i = LBound(keyArr) To UBound(keyArr)
        If map.exists(keyArr(i)) Then

            Set col = map(keyArr(i))
            n = nRowsArr(i)

            For c = 1 To n
                'select a random member of the collection
                rand = Application.Evaluate("RANDBETWEEN(1," & col.Count & ")")
                'Debug.Print keyArr(i), rand, col(rand)
                rawDataWs.Rows(col(rand)).Copy _
                     randomSampleWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                col.Remove rand 'remove the "used" row
                If col.Count = 0 Then
                    If c < n Then Debug.Print "Not enough rows for " & keyArr(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c

        Else
            'Debug.Print "No rows for " & keyArr(i)
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "Random Sample: Per Day Successfully Generated!"


End Sub

'get a map of rows as a dictionary where each value is a collection of row numbers
Function RowMap(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim dict, c As Range, k
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        k = Trim(c.value)
        If Len(k) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.exists(k) Then dict.Add k, New Collection
            dict(k).Add c.Row
        End If
    Next c
    Set RowMap = dict
End Function
```

Comment: `Set map = RowMap(rawDataWs.Range("A2:A23"))` did you adjust this line ?  Please don't update your original question to replace your code with my answer: it's easier for people coming later to follow if you just add a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified from your original code to focus on the approach:

```
Sub MAIN()

    Dim rawDataWs As Worksheet, randomSampleWs As Worksheet
    Dim map, i As Long, n As Long, c As Long, rand, col
    Dim keyArr, nRowsArr, rng

    Set rawDataWs = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set randomSampleWs = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    randomSampleWs.UsedRange.ClearContents

    'EDIT: dynamic range in ColA
    Set rng  = rawDataWs.Range("A2:A" & _
                    rawDataWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    Set map = RowMap(rng)

    keyArr = Array("AU", "FJ", "NC", "NZ", "SG12") '<== keywords
    nRowsArr = Array(4, 1, 1, 3, 10) '<== # of random rows

    Debug.Print "Key", "#", "Row#"
    For i = LBound(keyArr) To UBound(keyArr)
        If map.exists(keyArr(i)) Then

            Set col = map(keyArr(i))
            n = nRowsArr(i)

            For c = 1 To n
                'select a random member of the collection
                rand = Application.Evaluate("RANDBETWEEN(1," & col.Count & ")")
                Debug.Print keyArr(i), rand, col(rand)
                rawDataWs.Rows(col(rand)).Copy _
                     randomSampleWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                col.Remove rand 'remove the "used" row
                If col.Count = 0 Then
                    If c < n Then Debug.Print "Not enough rows for " & keyArr(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c

        Else
            Debug.Print "No rows for " & keyArr(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

'get a map of rows as a dictionary where each value is a collection of row numbers
Function RowMap(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim dict, c As Range, k
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        k = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(k) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.exists(k) Then dict.Add k, New Collection
            dict(k).Add c.Row
        End If
    Next c
    Set RowMap = dict
End Function
```

Comment: tried this but i got weird results. I don't understand why. I'm just new to VBA and I am having a hard time with what  i want to accomplish now

Comment: Did you adjust the "A2:A23" ?  That was just my simplified code using fixed input range containing some test data.  For testing you can just hard-code it to your current dataset.

Comment: yeah i did change. i just checked the rawdata.xlsx im using and it was modified. maybe it is the one that has problem. I have one question. How can i set the range to be dynamic? because I will have different amount of data every day. I tried With rawDataWs
    Set map = RowMap(rawDataWs.Range("A2:" & .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Address)
    End With but does not seem to work

Comment: See my edit.  I'm copying the whole row - if that's a problem you'll need to modify the `Copy` line

Comment: I had the same idea. I tried and i got Compile error:ByRef argument type mismatch Edit: I tried Dim rng As Range and it worked now. Thanks! If i got into another problem i will just put a comment in here again

Comment: I am having problem now. I used another file and named it the same. There is no error but not copying anything. I can only use one specific file to get rows even if it has the same content. What is wrong? I updated my code in my question

Comment: i will just post another question for this one since it is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can follow the logic as it is too complex for me.  If you don't mind, I worked out an alternative code.

EDIT: 
I was assuming you can modify the code to get the source/destination. I tested this in excel 2013 and assuming:

- the code is running from another work book (not source/destination).
- Key is in the first column.
- you will modify the oKey and oCnt as per your requirement.

  ```
  Dim oWS As Worksheet
  Dim oWSSrc As Worksheet

  Dim oWBSrc As Workbook
  Dim oWBDest As Workbook

  Dim oRng As Range
  Dim oStart As Range
  Dim oLast As Range
  Dim oMatch As Range
  Dim oDest As Range

  Dim oKey As Variant
  Dim oCnt As Variant

  Dim iCnt As Integer
  Dim iTot As Integer
  Dim iMatch As Integer

  oKey = Split("AU,FJ,NZ", ",") '<= modify this
  oCnt = Split("4,1,3", ",") ' <= modify this

  'Open Destination
  Set oWBDest = Application.Workbooks.Open("Tool.xlsm")
  Set oWS = oWBDest.Sheets.Add

  'Open source workbook
  Set oWBSrc = Application.Workbooks.Open("Rawdata.xlsx")
  Set oWSSrc = oWBSrc.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set oRng = oWSSrc.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
  oRng.Copy oWS.Cells(1, 1)

  oWBSrc.Close

  'assume key
  Set oStart = oWS.Cells(1, 1)

  Set oRng = oWS.Range(oStart, oStart.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown).Offset(1))

  oWBDest.Sheets("Random Sample").UsedRange.Clear
  Set oDest = oWBDest.Sheets("Random Sample").Cells(1, 1)

  Randomize

  'Assign random numbers for sorting
  For iCnt = 1 To oRng.Rows.Count - 1 ' last row is a dummy row do not assign
      oRng.Cells(iCnt, oRng.Columns.Count + 1) = Rnd()
  Next

  'sort by key (col1) and random number (last col)
  With oWS.Sort
      .SortFields.Clear
      .SortFields.Add oWS.Columns(1)
      .SortFields.Add oWS.Columns(oRng.Columns.Count + 1)
      .SetRange oWS.Range(oStart, oStart.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
      .Apply
  End With

  For iCnt = LBound(oKey) To UBound(oKey)

      'Find the first match
      Set oStart = oRng.Find(oKey(iCnt), oRng.Cells(oRng.Rows.Count, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
      Set oLast = oStart ' initiliase

      If Not oStart Is Nothing Then
          '-1 as the first one has been detected
          For iMatch = 1 To CInt(oCnt(iCnt)) - 1
              Set oMatch = oRng.Find(oKey(iCnt), oLast, xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)

              ' Match the same as start exit (means there are not enough row)
              If oMatch.Address = oStart.Address Then
                  Exit For
              Else
                  Set oLast = oMatch
              End If
          Next

          'copy the match to output
          Set oStart = oWS.Range(oStart, oLast.Offset(, oRng.Columns.Count - 1))

          oStart.Copy oDest

          If oDest.Offset(1).Value <> "" Then
              Set oDest = oDest.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
          Else
              Set oDest = oDest.Offset(1)
          End If
      End If
  Next

  'Cleaning up
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  oWS.Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  oWBDest.Save
  oWBDest.Close
  ```