# VBA Listbox Unique Values

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

I'm trying to create a macro that would allow me to report on certain clients from a database by selecting them using a userform and listboxes. I'm currently stuck on finding a way to select certain clients but process every row listed under that client.

The script I am using stores all unique values in a collection. I'm not sure how to call the collection in the run command button to process all rows that are tied to a selected client, meaning if I were to select CLN1 and CLN3 in the attached image, I would want rows 2:6 and 10:12 processed and the rest deleted.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i, rowrow As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Unique As New Collection
Dim Item As Range

LastNonEmptyRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myfile").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

On Error Resume Next
For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myfile").Range("A2:A" & rowrow)
    Unique.Add Cell, CStr(Cell)
Next Cell
On Error GoTo 0

For Each Item In Unique
   ListBox1.AddItem Item
Next Item

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks, all!

[Spreadsheet example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz_jT9PPDXajQXB1UjNHSjVNN1k/view?usp=sharing)

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Instead of a Collection you can use a Scripting Dictionary and store the rows in the Value (you can build up a Range object using Application.Union as you loop over the rows).  Make the Dictionary Global to the form so it doesn't go out of scope as soon as `UserForm_Initialize` is done executing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274110/vba-macro-to-copy-random-rows-based-on-multiple-conditions/36299983#36299983 for an example of this approach.

Comment: Which variable are you using? `rowrow` or `LastNonEmptyRow`? Did you set `Option Explicit`?

Answer (score 0):

assuming your run command button is called after `Run_Btn`, then you could start with this code in your userform code pane:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Long, rowrow As Long, LastNonEmptyRow As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Unique As New Collection
    Dim Item As Range

    LastNonEmptyRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myfile").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myfile").Range("A2:A" & LastNonEmptyRow)
        Unique.Add Cell, CStr(Cell)
    Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each Item In Unique
       ListBox1.AddItem Item
    Next Item
End Sub

Private Sub Run_Btn_Click()
    Dim deletedClients As String
    Dim i As Long

    With Me.ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If Not .Selected(i) Then deletedClients = deletedClients & .List(i) & " "
        Next
    End With
    If deletedClients <> "" Then ProcessData deletedClients
End Sub

Sub ProcessData(deletedClients As String)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myfile")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            DeleteData .Cells, deletedClients '<--| delete unselected clients records

            ' your code to "Process" remaining data

        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub DeleteData(rng As Range, deletedClients As String)
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Split(Trim(deletedClients), " "), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```